# Understanding my first project on my job

Tags: projects

I am on my first job after completing my studies. My company does not follow any good coding or documentation practices, just a few basic rules. So there is no documentation of my project or any comments in the code. My only source of help are my teammates who clear my doubts if I dont understand something and they explained me the basic structure of the project.

So any advice on how do I understand such a project considering I am completely new to the corporate world and have no prior experience to understanding projects.
What steps should I take to understand the project better?

I read the below link 
[Advice on how to understand a project with long history quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468651/advice-on-how-to-understand-a-project-with-long-history-quickly)
but in that situation he actually has docs to read.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the docs do not exist, somebody can probably write them. Unless they don't mind losing time every time a new person comes onto the project.

Comment: Start by solving bugs, it will get you familiar with different paths of the code. Continue by adding small features that require only working against specific (and small number of) classes. By doing this you'll increase your context and get even more familiar with the code in the project.

Comment: @Greg that's actually not a bad idea, only that this "someone" should be the new guy :) once he gets himself familiar with a certain module - he can add documentation and let his peers review it and add their context. If any new programmer in the team will follow it - the documentation will be added (slowly but surely).

Comment: Don't try to understand the whole project at once, at least not in detail, trying to understand every single line will get you frustated and you will lose time. Focus on a single module at a time.

Comment: @Greg - They just wont allow time for documentation and always overload with work. So basically I too cant do any documentation even if I want to. Thanks for the advice guys.Will definitely implement it.